# LibreOffice Dark Theme

Tags: libreoffice

I installed LibreOffice 6 *Snap* and it automatically inherited my Ubuntu 16.04 dark theme.

I installed LibreOffice 6 *Flatpak* and it **does not** automatically inherit my Ubuntu 16.04 dark theme.

Why? How do I enable the dark theme on my *Flatpak* LibreOffice?

Comment: Same here, on KDE Neon 20.04 LibreOffice 7 Flatpak and it does not automatically inherit system's dark theme.

Comment: Same problem in 2023!, 5 years with same ui error. Then they wonder why linux doesn't succeed on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

There is an active [issue](https://github.com/flathub/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/issues/130) on the FlatHub's GitHub. They recommend running this command:

```
flatpak override --user --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether we have the same problem, but for me, this helped:

```
sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice libreoffice-kde
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk libreoffice
```

see also https://github.com/flathub/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/issues/31 to see when the flatpack issue will be fixed